# Remove first 2 php objects from array

Tags: php

I am want remove first 2 object from a PHP array, my code is as below

```
print_r($available_methods);
```

Output:

```
    Array ( 
[free_shipping:5] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object ( [id] => free_shipping:5 [label] => International Free [cost] => 0.00 [taxes] => Array ( ) [method_id] => free_shipping [meta_data:WC_Shipping_Rate:private] => Array ( [Items] => Portsea Polo - 2018 × 1 ) ) 

[flat_rate:4] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object ( [id] => flat_rate:4 [label] => International Regular [cost] => 34 [taxes] => Array ( ) [method_id] => flat_rate [meta_data:WC_Shipping_Rate:private] => Array ( [Items] => Portsea Polo - 2018 × 1 ) ) 

[per_product] => WC_Shipping_Rate Object ( [id] => per_product [label] => Express shipping [cost] => 9.00 [taxes] => Array ( ) [method_id] => per_product [meta_data:WC_Shipping_Rate:private] => Array ( ) ) 
)
```

I want to remove first 2 array indexes and use only last one.

Comment: why you don't just pick up the last one into a Variable ?

Comment: I have to use it many times so i am want unset first 2

Comment: yes, you pick the last one and you put it again on the var

Comment: If your array always has 3 elements - then `array_pop` last one and save in a var.

Comment: Solved by:  unset($available_methods['free_shipping:5']);
            unset($available_methods['flat_rate:4']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `unset()`

You could simply just unset the first 2 index values if the key doesn't change.

```
unset($available_methods["free_shipping:5"]);
unset($available_methods["flat_rate:4"]);
```

But, there are definitely other ways that may be better for your situation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

---

## `array_pop()`

An alternative to unsetting the other variables is using `array_pop`.

```
$available_methods = [array_pop($available_methods)];
```

Notice that I wrapped it in square brackets `[]` which puts it back into an array. (The brackets are shorthand arrays)

If you don't care about it being in an array, you can just drop these symbols and it will be in a variable on it's own.

```
$available_methods = array_pop($available_methods);
```

> array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening
>   the array by one element.

In this form, this will overwrite the existing array completely with the data from the last index, but you could just as easily save it to a different variable so you can keep your original data in existence as well.

More information on `array_pop()` can be found in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

---

## It could get even easier

If it's always an exact index, and that index is always named the same, you could very simply just pull that index into it's own variable.

```
$available_methods = [$available_methods['per_product']]; //to keep it in an array
$available_methods = $available_methods['per_product']; //to keep just the variable
```

---

**NOTE:** If you are running a PHP version less than 5.4 (Which, if you are, you should definitely upgrade to a newer version), the short array syntax is not supported and will have to be replaced with `array()`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**NOTE:** All of these solutions will probably perform very nearly the same, choosing between the different ones based on how long they take to perform would probably be considered micro-optimization, which in most cases does not matter very much. You should just choose the one that is the easiest for you to understand how it works, or maybe even the one you understand the least so that you can learn how it works. That is what I would do :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
unset($available_methods["free_shipping:5"]);
unset($available_methods["flat_rate:4"]);
```

Comment: Solved by :  unset($available_methods['free_shipping:5']);
            unset($available_methods['flat_rate:4']);

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using array_slice.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Something like the following:

```
$list = array_slice($available_methods, 2, null, true);
```

Comment: Nice! I can't believe I didn't think of that!